# What is a delicate way of identifying key insiders?

Tags: advisor, mentoring

I am beginning a doctoral program this Fall and have been receiving helpful advice from a recent graduate. While this graduate has mentioned a key mentor that will likely serve as my primary advisor, I am curious to know if there were other mentors instrumental to his success in the program.

What might be a delicate way of inquiring who these people are?

EDIT: I was initially afraid that having someone identify the "good guys" might imply that I reckon that some are "bad." But this is probably overthinking it, as one comment pointed out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like a delicate question, so I don't understand why it would need to be asked in a delicate way.  I'd just say it: "What other people would you recommend as mentors?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just emphasize one thing: there are very few *objectively* good advisors/mentors. It really depends on both the mentor and the student’s personality. Some prefer a more hands on approach while others like to be independent. Some are motivated by harsh criticism while others need a more gentle approach.

To conclude, I think what you’d want to ask is more “what is Professor A like?” rather than whether they’re good/bad mentors.